# How to sum total of rows in html table - binded in phpmyadmin

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table within html. the data was being fetched from phpmyadmin using php. and I want to total the values in each row. Please Help.

```
<?php
// Connect to the database
$dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'ghsexam_database');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Query for a list of all existing files
$sql = 'SELECT `last_name`, `first_name`, `middle_initial`, `educ_attain`, `logic1`, 
`logic2`,`logic3`,  `grammar1`, `grammar2`, `grammar3`, `grammar4`, `grammar5`, `ghs_essay`, 
`reading1`, `reading2`, `reading3`, `reading4`, `listening1`, `listening2` FROM `ghs_table` ';

$result = $dbLink->query($sql);


// Check if it was successfull
if($result) {
// Make sure there are some files in there
if($result->num_rows == 0) {

    echo '<p>There are no files in the database</p>';
}
else {
    // Print the top of a table
    echo '<center><table id=myTable table border=4 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 width="100%">
            <tr class="header">

                <th onclick="sortTable(0)" style="cursor:pointer; "nowrap="nowrap"><b>Last Name</b> 
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>

                <th onclick="sortTable(1)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"><b>First Name</b> 
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(2)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"><b>Middle 
Initial</b><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(3)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"><b>Educational 
Attainment</b><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>

                <th onclick="sortTable(4)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"><b>Logic:1:</b><i 
class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>

                <th onclick="sortTable(5)" style="cursor:pointer;"><b>Logic:2</b><i class="fa fa-fw 
fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(6)" style="cursor:pointer;"><b>Logic3</b><i class="fa fa-fw 
fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(7)" style="cursor:pointer;"><b>Grammar:1</b><i class="fa fa- 
fw fa-sort"></i></th>

                <th onclick="sortTable(8)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"><b>Grammar:2</b> 
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(9)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"><b>Grammar:3</b> 
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(11)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"><b>Grammar:4</b> 
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(12)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"><b>Grammar:5</b> 
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(13)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"> 



 <b>Essay Writing</b><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(14)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"><b>Reading:1</b> 
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(15)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"><b>Reading:2</b> 
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(16)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"><b>Reading:3</b>                
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(17)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"><b>Reading:4</b> 
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(18)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"> 
<b>Listening:1</b><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(19)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"> 
<b>Listening:2</b><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(20)" style="cursor:pointer;" nowrap="nowrap"><b>Total</b><i 
class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>

            </tr>';

    // Print each file
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>{$row['last_name']}</td>
                <td>{$row['first_name']}</td>
                <td>{$row['middle_initial']}</td>
                <td>{$row['educ_attain']}</td>
                <td class='count-me'>{$row['logic1']}</td>
                <td class='count-me'>{$row['logic2']}</td>
                <td class='count-me'>{$row['logic3']}</td>
                <td class='count-me'>{$row['grammar1']}</td>
                <td class='count-me'>{$row['grammar2']}</td>
                <td class='count-me'>{$row['grammar3']}</td>
                <td class='count-me'>{$row['grammar4']}</td>
                <td class='count-me'>{$row['grammar5']}</td>
                <td>{$row['ghs_essay']}</td>
                <td class='count-me'>{$row['reading1']}</td>
                <td class='count-me'>{$row['reading2']}</td>
                <td class='count-me'>{$row['reading3']}</td>
                <td class='count-me'>{$row['reading4']}</td>
                <td class='count-me'>{$row['listening1']}</td>
                <td class='count-me'>{$row['listening2']}</td>
```

I have a problem in this part. I want to total the limited values on each rows. like, 1 1 1 1 1 = 5.
Fill free to comment down below.[Click this to see the output][1]

```
    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>

        var tds = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('td');
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
            if(tds[i].className == 'count-me') {
                sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML += '<td>as<td>' + sum + '</td>';
    </script>



            </tr>";
    }

    // Close table
     echo '</table></center>';
}

  // Free the result
 $result->free();
}
 else
{
 echo 'Error! SQL query failed:';
 echo "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
 }

 // Close the mysql connection
 $dbLink->close();
 ?>


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpG2b.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand it right. Do you want to sum up columns in each row? Like logic1+logic2+logic3? If it is what You want try something like this:

```
$sql = '
SELECT 
    `last_name`,
    `first_name`,
    `middle_initial`,
    `educ_attain`,
    `logic1`,
    `logic2`,
    `logic3`,
    (`logic1`+`logic2`+`logic3`) AS logic_sum,
FROM
    `ghs_table`
';
```

In logic_sum you will get all logic columns summed up. And repeat it of course for grammar, reading and listening. Hope it helps.

Comment: Absolutely Yes!, each column has a integer value came from the phpmyadmin database, aside from the ghs_essay, so it was not included, eveyone of 14 columns might have a 1, 0 , 1, 1, 0 value, so what I want in the total column for row is to total the sum of it like, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 = 5 in the total column only on the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your code with as below:

```js
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
  var sum = 0;
  $('td').each(function(){
    var tdTxt = $(this).text();
      if($(this).hasClass('count-me')) {
        $(this).text(sum);
        sum = 0;
      } else {
        sum+= parseFloat(tdTxt);    
      } 
  });
  document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML += '<td>as<td>' + sum + '</td>';
    </script>
```

I hope it would help you out.